# Pandas writing to excel: 1) blank row from index; 2) keep index daily

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I've traditionally used Stata for data analysis, but I've been exploring pandas today. I successfully replicated some analysis I did in Stata, but I'm having a hard time exporting it to excel.

Example of what I'm getting with write_excel()

```
                         Column1  Column2
    Date        
    2014-01-01 00:00:00  x        a
    2014-01-02 00:00:00  y        b
    2014-01-03 00:00:00  z        c
```

1. I'd like to align the index so that it's in line with the column headers. Essentially, I'd like to keep the column headers where they are, but shift everything up by one cell.
2. I want my index to only have the date (YYYY-MM-DD) without the hours, minutes, and seconds (it's always 00:00:00). How do I change my index to only have the date?

Much thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What worked for me was to reset the index so that 'Date' becomes an ordinary column, then call the `dt` property `date` to assign back just the date portion and when writing to excel pass param `index=False`:

```
In [34]:

df = df.reset_index()
df['Date'] = df.Date.dt.date
df
Out[34]:
         Date Column1 Column2
0  2014-01-01       x       a
1  2014-01-02       y       b
2  2014-01-03       z       c
```

and then

```
df.to_excel(r'c:\data\t.xlsx',index=False)
```

This results in the following in excel:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think the most simple and easy way of handling pandas DatetimeIndex format is kwarg of pandas ExcelWriter itself.

```
datetime_format='yyyy-mm-dd'
```

for example,

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

'''
Suppose that there is 'df' the pandas dataframe which contains DatetimeIndex(ex. 2015-04-15 10:15:30) as index.
'''

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('result.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter', datetime_format='yyyy-mm-dd')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

writer.save()
```

For any other cell(batch/individual) formatting, use xlsxwriter add_format(), set_column(), etc.

Answer (score 2):

(1) Mimicking your format:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import *

df = pd.read_csv('input.txt',sep=',',header=None,names=['Date','Column A','Column B'])

df = df.set_index(['Date'])
```

(2) Doing a reindexing:

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

(3) To excel

```
writer = ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1',index=False)
writer.save()
```

Note:
For the excel writer you will need to have openpyxl. A breeze to install with `pip install openxl`. Info on this here: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/. 
Alternatively, a write to csv would be more trivial.

---

Example of implementation in context of steps above in ipython:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: from pandas import *

In [3]: # 1. Mimicking your format:

In [4]: df = pd.read_csv('input.txt',sep=',',header=None,names=['Date','Column A','Column B'])

In [5]: print ( df )
                  Date Column A Column B
0  2014-01-01 00:00:00        x        a
1  2014-01-02 00:00:00        y        b
2  2014-01-03 00:00:00        z        c

In [6]: df = df.set_index(['Date'])

In [7]: print ( df )
                    Column A Column B
Date                                 
2014-01-01 00:00:00        x        a
2014-01-02 00:00:00        y        b
2014-01-03 00:00:00        z        c

In [8]: ## 2. Doing a reindexing:

In [9]: df = df.reset_index()

In [10]: print ( df )
                  Date Column A Column B
0  2014-01-01 00:00:00        x        a
1  2014-01-02 00:00:00        y        b
2  2014-01-03 00:00:00        z        c

In [11]: ## 3. To excel

In [12]: writer = ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')

In [13]: df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1',index=False)

In [14]: writer.save()
```